# Invalid meeting id when get meeting infos using teamsFx sdk

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I would like to retrieve meeting infos using the react TeamsFx library

this is how I do :

```
const meetingInfos = (graph: Client)=> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        microsoftTeams.getContext( async context=>{
            console.log("contexxt",context);
            let meeting;
            const meetingId= atob(context.meetingId || '') 
            try {
            meeting = await graph.api(`/me/onlineMeetings/${context.chatId}`).get();
                console.log("meeeting",meeting);
                resolve(meeting);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("reject error",error);
                reject(error);
            }
            console.log(meeting);

        })
    })
}
```

I tried also to convert `context.meetingId`to b64 but I get same error ( I figured out that `chatId` encoded to b64 = `meetingId` )

Actually I'm getting this error:

> "Invalid meeting id
> 19:meeting_MzU0MzFhYTQtNjlmOS00NGI4LTg1MTYtMGI3ZTkwOWYwMzk4@thread.v2."

How to get the correct meeting id ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow this way to get the meetinng info.

> GET /me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'{joinWebUrl}'

Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-retrieve-an-online-meeting-by-joinweburl

Comment: I don't find the joinWebUrl element in the `context` object of teamsFX useGraph hook. How can I get it ?